# Usergrid: How do I delete collections

Tags: node.js, apigee, usergrid

Once again an usergrid question. Something that I cant find in the docu. How do I delete a collection? Not the entities in the collection. But the collection itself. As per Apigee's ReSTful guideline webinar, I understand that collection name should always be plural.

I have a collection called **showroom**, but I want to call it **showrooms**. Would like to delete collection showroom and create showrooms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately deleting collections is not currently supported for Apigee API BaaS.

Answer (score 0):

I ran up against this too and seems to be a common question.  I did find a gist that helps delete collections in batches of 10 by deleting one at a time.

https://gist.github.com/r3mus/11704dc5b7395108c205

In addition, if found that if you do something like

```
DELETE http://xxxxx.com/appservices/xxxxx/collection?ql=select * where isError = false
```

It will delete up to 1k entities at a time.  This approach works if you want to run it using a cursor to remove till empty.

Comment: that deletes entities, not collections. There seems to be no way to get rid of a collection entirely. I don't want to delete the rows of a table, I want to delete the table itself - that's the issue here

Comment: Your right.  This does seem to be a common question for those first getting started.